# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, extjs

- I am working on extjs framework..

  - i have an application running on extjs..
  - whenever i open the application in the browser...i see the following
    warnings in my console...

**Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/**

- can you guys tell me how to remove it..
- when i click the warning it takes to ext-all-debug-w-comments.js file
- and points to the following part of code...

  try {
                      xhr.open('GET', noCacheUrl, false);
                      xhr.send(null);
                  } catch (e) {
                      isCrossOriginRestricted = true;
                  }
- can you guys tell me how to prevent it from happening...
- providing my code below in that file

  /**
           * Load a script file, supports both asynchronous and synchronous approaches
           * @private
           */
          loadScriptFile: function(url, onLoad, onError, scope, synchronous) {
              if (isFileLoaded[url]) {
                  return Loader;
              }

  ```
          var config = Loader.getConfig(),
              noCacheUrl = url + (config.disableCaching ? ('?' + config.disableCachingParam + '=' + Ext.Date.now()) : ''),
              isCrossOriginRestricted = false,
              xhr, status, onScriptError,
              debugSourceURL = "";

          scope = scope || Loader;

          Loader.isLoading = true;

          if (!synchronous) {
              onScriptError = function() {
              };

              scriptElements[url] = Loader.injectScriptElement(noCacheUrl, onLoad, onScriptError, scope);
          } else {
              if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
                  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
              } else {
                  xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
              }

              try {
                  xhr.open('GET', noCacheUrl, false);
                  xhr.send(null);
              } catch (e) {
                  isCrossOriginRestricted = true;
              }

              status = (xhr.status === 1223) ? 204 :
                  (xhr.status === 0 && (self.location || {}).protocol == 'file:') ? 200 : xhr.status;

              isCrossOriginRestricted = isCrossOriginRestricted || (status === 0);

              if (isCrossOriginRestricted
              ) {
              }
              else if ((status >= 200 && status < 300) || (status === 304)
              ) {
                  // Debugger friendly, file names are still shown even though they're eval'ed code
                  // Breakpoints work on both Firebug and Chrome's Web Inspector
                  if (!Ext.isIE) {
                      debugSourceURL = "\n//@ sourceURL=" + url;
                  }

                  Ext.globalEval(xhr.responseText + debugSourceURL);

                  onLoad.call(scope);
              }
              else {
              }

              // Prevent potential IE memory leak
              xhr = null;
          }
      },
  ```

Comment: `xhr.open('GET', noCacheUrl, false);` Remove the `false`. But then you’ll have to move everything below the `try-catch` statement into an event handler like this `xhr.addEventListener('load',function(){` …code… `})`.

Comment: @xufox its confusing can you update in the code in the below fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e1hfjue1/

Comment: It only happens when you're using dynamic loading. It's not really a problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e1hfjue1/1/ Something like this. I can’t verify whether it actually works because I haven’t got the full script.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli but how to remove that warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning is only showing in Chrome in the development environment of ExtJs. Once the application is built with `sencha cmd`, the warning doesn't show anymore. As @Evan pointed out the warning looks benign, and you should not have to worry about it.

The fact that there is a warning should not be an issue, since it will never show in a deployed application. If you do not yet use sencha cmd, it is definitely worth to integrate it in your development cycle.

I know it is not a direct answer to the question. Myself, I wonder if it is possible to get rid of this warning at all.

Comment: thanks for your reply...is there demo where i can look which help us in better understanding,,,

Comment: For sencha cmd, the demo is simple : download it, `sencha generate app`, then `sencha app build`, and you have a demo app.

Comment: can you share a fiddle with working simple, hard to understand :(